# Cannot upload VHD to azure failing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a VHD file to azure. I am using the command line to set the connection and start the upload. WHen it is doing the upload it calculates the HASH and then it starts uploading the file but then it fails and a very long message.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10>csupload Add-Pers
istentVMImage -Destination "http://testrli.blob.core.windows.net/test3/EO Testin
g.vhd" -Label "EO Testing.vhd" -LiteralPath "C:\VIRTUALMACHINES\PAT5DB\EO Traini
ng.vhd" -OS Windows
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Upload Tool version 1.8.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Use of http is insecure, can leak data to untrusted viewers and make your   contentvulnerable to data tampering by a malicious third party.
Using the saved connection string...
Using image name 'EOTraining.vhd'
Found existing page blob. Resuming upload...
MD5 hash is being calculated for the file 'C:\VIRTUALMACHINES\PAT5DB\EO Training
.vhd'.
MD5 hash calculation is completed.ning Time: 00:00:01; Throughput: 1344.2Mbps
Elapsed time for the operation: 00:12:27
Upload failed with exceptions:
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encounte
red an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected erro
r occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOExcepti
on: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection wa
s forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
n existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebReq
uest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Upload.BlobSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Sy
nchronize>b__1(DataWithRange dwr, CloudPageBlob b)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Sync.Threading.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<ForEa
ch>b__1(Object )
Elapsed time for upload: 00:02:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things to note here.

1. You are using http endpoint so please use HTTP to avoid further warnings and complications i.e. https://testrli.blob.core.windows.net/test3/EO
2. Please update your connection string to use correct certificate

The upload is trying to resume a previous upload and during the upload the connection is closed from server side. Sometime resume upload may spew these error so a fresh upload does help.

Also I would suggest using the Powershell (download latest 0.6.11) and enable $DebugPreference ='Continue' to see the request and response on console this way if you met any problem you will know the probable cause.

Here is PS script to upload a VM to Windows Azure: 
http://michaelwasham.com/2013/01/04/migrate-a-virtual-machine-to-windows-azure-with-powershell/

Also report your issues to [Windows Azure VM Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/threads) to get 1:1 support from respective team, if problem still persist.

Comment: i changed the connection to https and it worked. thanks a lot.